# Button to increase number until 50 and then start to decrease until 0 or lower, creating loop

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've been trying to get this right but I always end up in a loop that gets to 50 or more  and then whenever the number is lower than 50 it increases again, instead of decreasing. Even sometimes it gets stuck at 50 or more

```
@State var number = 0
    @State var inverseNumber = 50
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            
            Text(String (number))
                .padding()
            Button(action: {
                if number <= 50 && (inverseNumber <= 50) {
                increase()
                }
                else if number >= 0 && (inverseNumber >= 0){

                        decrease()
                
                }
                
            }, label: {
                Text("Increase or Decrease")
            })
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
    func increase() {
        var randNum = Int.random(in: 1...10)
        number = number + randNum
        inverseNumber = inverseNumber - randNum
    }
    func decrease()  {
        var randNum = Int.random(in: 1...10)
        number = number - randNum
        inverseNumber = inverseNumber + randNum
    }
```

Comment: Create a boolean variable in which you store whether you are currently increasing or decreasing.

Comment: So you increase and decrease by a random amount. Are you okay with overshooting 50 or 0 or do you need to check for the limits? Why is `inverseNumber` changing?

Comment: @jnpdx I'm okay overshooting 50 and 0. inverseNumber was just an attempt to try and solve it

Comment: `number = isIncreasing ? number + Int.random(in: 1...10) : number -Int.random(in: 1...10)`. Then check `number` directly after and toggle isIncreasing if it is >50 or <0

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, storing the direction is probably the missing component. Also, for others reading, as noted in the comments, overshooting is acceptable in the OP's scenario.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var number = 0
    @State private var increasing = true
    private var inverseNumber = 50
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("\(number)")
                .padding()
            Button(action: {
                if increasing && number >= inverseNumber { increasing = false }
                if !increasing && number <= 0 { increasing = true }
                if increasing {
                    number += Int.random(in: 1...10)
                } else {
                    number -= Int.random(in: 1...10)
                }
            }) {
                Text("Increase or decrease")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this could be condensed into shorter code (just a couple of one liners using tertiaries), but I've left it a little verbose for readability and understanding the concept of what's going on.

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so, you can mark it as accepted using the green checkmark